# loop problem with goto in php

Tags: php, loops, goto

I have programmed a script with the `goto` command but on the server where I want to execute the script there is a previous PHP version (<5.3), so I have to change the code. The structure of the code goes like that:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++)  // print 30 articles 
{
    $x = 0;
    // choose a a feed from the db
    // parse it

    a:
    foreach($feed->get_items($x, 1) as $item)
    {
        // create a unique id for the article of the feed

      if($id == $dbid)
      {
          // if this id exists in the db, take the next article of the same feed which is not in the db 
          $x++;
          goto a;
      }
      else
      {
          // print the original article you grabbed
      }

   } // end of foreach
} // end of for
```

I have tested everything. Do you have any ideas how can I retransform this code without `goto` in order to be executed properly???

Comment: had to delete my 1st answer after the original code was edited

Comment: This is why GOTO is evil. IT's always pretty hard to determine the work flow

Comment: @yes123: obligatory: http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: +1 for trying to re-factor to remove goto :) GJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how the `->get_items()` call behaves you could use this brute-force method in lieu of the goto-switch:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 30; $i++)
{
    $x = 0;


    $a = 1;
    while ($a--)
    foreach($feed->get_items($x, 1) as $item)
    {

      if($id == $dbid)
      {
          $x++;
          $a=1; break;
      }
      else
      {
      }

   } // end of foreach
} // end of for
```

The label gets replaced by a `while` and a self-fulfulling stop condition. And the goto becomes a break and resets the `$a` stop condition.

Comment: This code is still obfuscated like the code with the goto you posted. You may have removed the goto but it's not gone in spirit. Even though it seems clear to you now, the code will not be so for others (and even to you some months down the line). The standard way to do this is with a flag which marks if you found a matching id in the db.

Comment: @Anupam: True. That's just a raw transliteration of the goto. (Examplifies the purpose of that simplified syntax construct however). But without knowing the exact relation of the `$i` and `$x` and `->get_item` behaviour it's difficult to label and restructure it more appropriately.

Comment: It is possible to restructure the code without knowing all the details. Look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238050/loop-problem-with-goto-in-php/6238512#6238512).

Comment: @Anupam: Same structure, but obviously better labeled and more descriptive +1

Answer (score 2):

This questions demonstrates why goto should be avoided. It lets you get away without thinking about the algorithm enough.

The standard way to do this is with a flag. I hope you were not expecting a "herezthecode kthxbai" sort of an answer, but in this case the best way to explain it would be to write the code -

```
for($i=0;$i<30;$++){
  $x=0;
  do {
    $found = false;
    foreach($feed->get_items($x,1) as $item){
      // get $id
      if($id==$dbid){
        $found = true;
        break;
      }else{
        // other things
      }
    }
    $x++;
  } while($found);
}
```

Comment: Hi my friend.Yeah this code has a similar structure with the suggestion of mario.It is obvious that goto is both a blessing and a curse the same time.Mostly a curse.It can make things easier most times but this is not good.It makes programmers more lazy.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would probably work...

```
function loop(){
  foreach($feed->get_items($x,1) as $item){
    if($id==$dbid){
      $x++;
      loop();
    }else{

    }
  }
}
for($i=0;$i<30;$++){
  $x=0;
  loop();
}
```

I'm sorry, I removed all the comments, they were annoying.

Comment: I am going to test it and i will tell you if it works..i tried something like that with if statements but it did not worked correctly.

Comment: be careful about recursion.  Go too many layers deep and you'll cause PHP to segfault.  (It does take quite a few layers deep though)

Comment: You need to declare $x as a global.

Answer (score 0):

Move the declaration of $x outside of the for loop and replace your label/goto combination with a break, like so...

```
    $x=0;
    for($i=0;$i<30;$++)  //print 30 articles 
    {
     foreach($feed->get_items($x,1) as $item)
     {
       //  create a unique id for the article of the feed
       if($id==$dbid)
       {
       //if this id exists in the db,take the next article of the same feed which is not in the db 
          $x++;
          continue;
       }
       else
       {
         //print the original article you grabbed
       }

     } // end of foreach
   }//end of for
```

Comment: @odsidian: i don't -1 because i like you but break; should be continue; ^^

Comment: @obsidian: yeah, but by doing that the script will not try to grab another feed from the db, if the article is not in the db..the comments you omitted in your answer..

Comment: @yes123 - actually, it should be continue 2; (basically break)  -- look at the original code, it was jumping out of the loop using goto.

Comment: @yes123 wait, hold on...you might be right.  CURSED GOTO WHY DID YOU HAVE TO BE ADDED TO 5.3.  BAD GOTO, BAD BAD.

Comment: @olaf36 @yes123 changed break to continue in my code snip.  that should allow it to work properly

Comment: Can you guys please give the goto commentary a rest? The syntax construct in PHP has nothing to do with a common jump or actual goto; and the bickering here looks just silly.

Comment: you just need to replace breack with continue. I am not kidding. I am a true master of PHP goto I KNOW what I ma talking about!! YODA

Comment: @mario: you can't know if after the If else block there is some code.

Comment: the comments mean that there is code that does what the comments explain.after else there is not any code

Answer (score -1):

Agree with unset - using break will break if loop and keep iterating through for loop

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php break does not affect if blocks.